# how to search through multiple workbooks for a specific word and get a few cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I need a code to do the following;

Im using a workbook, which is my main workbook that I work from, call it main.xlsx
Now in this workbook in;

sheet1, cell A6 = Item 1

Sheet1, cell D6 = Item Weight

Sheet1, cell I6 = Item Price

And in the same workbook;

Sheet3, cell A1 = Workbook Name

Sheet3, cell B1 = Item Name

Sheet3, cell C1 = Item Weight

Sheet3, cell D1 = Item Amount

Sheet3, cell G2 = (the cell where I type in my search value, e.g Item 1)

Sheet3, button =  Button 2

Now, with my main workbook, in sheet 1, I create and save multiple receipts to a folder, which would be for e.g copy1.xlsx, copy2.xlsx, ect. 
All the cell values will be constant in sheet 1.

In my main.xlsx workbook, sheet3 I want to be able to search through all those workbook copy's for a specific item, and display its name, weight and the price.

So if I type in Item 3 into cell G2 and click the button, the cell value in A2 to D2 will be populated accordingly.

So

Sheet3, cell A2 = Copy1.xlsx

Sheet3, cell B2 = Item 3

Sheet3, cell C2 = 5

Sheet3, cell D2 = 30

I apologize in advance for any complications.

Comment: What's your question? Perhaps something like this: How can I get the code for this without doing it myself?

Comment: I forgot to do so, technically yes, I need a code that would be able to do that, with a single click of a button

Comment: What have you tried? This site is (supposedly) not for spoonfeeding.

Comment: SJR - I've tried this https://excel.tips.net/T005598_Searching_Through_Many_Workbooks.html

Comment: But its not what I want, and I don't know how to adjust to my needs. Just a noob